# PHP MYSQLI issue with query - error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, syntax, mysqli

I'm trying to run this query with mysqli :

```
"SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION['username']['user_id']." AND status = 'Paused'"
```

And I'm getting the following error :

> There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'Paused\'' at line 1]

I've searched for a solution but found none.

Any suggestions?

---

More code

```
public function query($query) {
    $query = $this->db2->real_escape_string($query);

    if(!$result = $this->db2->query($query)) {
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $this->db2->error . ']');
    }

    $this->count = $result->num_rows;

    return mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $result->free();
}
```

Comment: Suggestion 1 would be use parameter binding... Aside from that, post the PHP implementation of that query.

Comment: Ouch, nobody noticed there is SQL injection issues?

Comment: can you echo $_SESSION['username']['user_id'] to see what is output here?

Comment: @Raptor Theres no SQL injection issue here, I'm using the real_escape_string function

Comment: Seems to me the problem is around `\'Paused\'` and not necessarily around the session variable interpolation (though that's a problem too). We need to see more **actual PHP code** before being able to answer this.

Comment: @AmirMendelson No you're not!

Comment: @Phil This is how my query function looks like :

public function query($query) {

$query = $this->db2->real_escape_string($query);

if(!$result = $this->db2->query($query)) {
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $this->db2->error . ']');

}

$this->count = $result->num_rows;
return mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$result->free();

}

Comment: You know what? Looking at Phil's message and your query it appears like you are running `mysql_real_escape_string` function on the ***whole*** query, which is equivalent to sprinkling sugar on ****

Comment: @AmirMendelson Well, your problem is that you're running the entire query through `real_escape_string`. This method is meant for parameter values only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd really avoid query wrapper methods as they make it difficult to provide parameter values, especially to *mysqli*. Start with something more prescriptive, for example

```
public function getUserCampaigns($userId, $status) {
    $stmt = $this->db2->prepare('SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE user_id = ? AND status = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('is', $userId, $status);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    return $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

and call it with

```
$campaigns = $obj->getUserCampaigns($_SESSION['username']['user_id'], 'Paused');
```

I also **highly recommend** you run this before creating your `mysqli` connection instance

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

as this will make *mysqli* report errors as exceptions, thus avoiding the need to write a bunch of error checking code.